# How to use scope correctly?

Tags: javascript, scope

I am not sure when to put variable to the top versus inside of the function.

I tried putting variable up top and sometimes inside the function. However, there are cases where it's not always inside as it is in this case.

```
function transformFirstAndLast(array){
    var first = array[0];
    var last = array[array.length-1];
    var squid = {};

    squid[first] = last;
    return squid;
}
```

vs

```
var first = array[0];
var last = array[array.length-1];
var squid = {};

function transformFirstAndLast(array){
    squid[first] = last;
    return squid;
}
```

the first one works. however, I thought that you can access the variables since it's global scope? I am confused why the second one does not work?

Comment: The general rule is that variables should be confined to the smallest scope they need. If you don't need to access a variable in multiple functions, it shouldn't be a global variable.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. If I run your code with an `var array = ['first', 'second', 'last']` in global scope your function returns `{first: 'last'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with the second code is that you are trying to access something that does not exist:

```
var first = array[0]; // <-- trying to access 'array'
var last = array[array.length-1]; // <-- trying to access 'array'
var squid = {};

function transformFirstAndLast(array){ // <-- 'array' is an argument of this function, and therefore only exists inside of the function
    squid[first] = last;
    return squid;
}
```

In JavaScript, you can access variables that are declared in the scope that you are in, and your parents.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your last example:

```
var first = array[0];
var last = array[array.length-1];
var squid = {};

function transformFirstAndLast(array){
    squid[first] = last;
    return squid;
}
```

At line 1, `array` is `undefined` since it's not in the current scope. The variable `array` only exists within the `transformFirstAndLast`-method. If you would call this method what would happen is:

- `squid` existst: `{}`
- `first` and `last` are both `undefined`
- We assign the property `undefined` (= `first`) to the object `squid` with value `undefined` (= `last`)
- We return `{ undefined: undefined }`

You declare variables where you need them. In this case `first` and `last` only make sense if you have an `array`, so inside the method.